# Get SQL parent key column name and table name of a child

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

So I know what the all the child foreign keys are by looking

```
 SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS;
```

However I now need to get what the parents of the foreign keys are called and what tables they are stored in.
So I need the SQL to return a table which stores the following data:

```
| Child Table | Child Column | Parent Table     | Parent Column |
=================================================================
| #_article   | category     | #_category_store | id            |
```

I have tried using this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS;
```

However that only gives me the child table and parent table. I cant then find the parent column.

Comment: I see that is perfect. I couldn't find that question through the many ways i typed out this question.